# How do I deploy applications in run as administrator mode?

Tags: windows, delphi, deployment, uac

How Do I deploy applications so that they require administrator rights without the end-user doing that by hand?

I use Delphi 2009 to build the application.

Comment: What do you use to deploy your program? (It's quite relevant since you may need your installer to generate shortcuts that have the "run as admin" flag set.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inform Windows that your application needs to run as an administrator by using the `requestedExecutionLevel` element in your application manifest.

The manifest file is an XML file that looks as follows. It should be named *YourApp.exe.manifest* and placed in the same folder as the executable. (It can also be embedded in the resources of your application; it must have a resource type of `RT_MANIFEST` and an ID of 1.)

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="YourApp" type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

For further details on application manifests and how to create them, see [Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) at MSDN.

Note that the manifest is only respected by Windows Vista and later. If your user is running as a standard user on Windows XP, your application will not be launched as an administrator; you may need to write code to detect this if it will be a problem for your application.

Comment: i tried your solutino using a new VCL Forms application on delphi xe2, creating a txt file with the content you put above from <assembly to /assembly>, embedded in resources forcing ID = 1 and RT_MANIFEST ad type, i compile but then as i run it nothing happens, should I expect windows to force me to run as admin?

Comment: @user193655: Have you turned UAC off? If so, then Windows won't prompt you to elevate. Otherwise, the steps you described sound correct. You'd probably be better off posting the full details as a new question; there may be some subtle Delphi-specific problem (that I don't know about) that other Delphi users could answer for you.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger : from where we on UAC ?

Answer (score 2):

Another option, although not recommended for "every day applications", is to name your executable with "Install" or "Setup" as part of the name.  Keep in mind that if you don't change any registry settings, or create any new files then windows will display a warning to the user that the program might not have run properly.